# reCAPTCHA Error for site owner: Invalid key type

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I keep getting **ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type** in frontend after implemennting recaptcha and **invalid-input-response** in the backend

Please how can i solve this?

I tried adding localhost to the list of domain but it is still not working.